# Spinner won't display +/- controller

Tags: jsf, primefaces, primefaces-mobile

I'm using primefaces version 5.3 and I want to show a basic spinner which I have copy-pasted from primefaces showcase.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
 xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
 xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
 xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
 xmlns:pm="http://primefaces.org/mobile">

<h:head></h:head>
<h:body>
 <pm:page>
    <pm:content>

        <h:form>
            <h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="5" class="ui-grid">

                <h:outputLabel for="basic" value="Basic Spinner: " />
                <p:spinner id="basic" value="#{spinnerView.number1}" />
            </h:panelGrid>
        </h:form>

    </pm:content>
</pm:page>
</h:body>
</html>
```

The incrementer/decrementer part won't show.

Comment: known issue in PrimeFaces 0.9.6 (and why not post an [mcve]) instead of two code snippets? Might be lots of invisible css applied that affects this. Might be device related and what more. Please investigate as a developer, not an end-user

Comment: oh and btw, your `f:view renderKitId="..." should be a tag around your content, not an empty tag